Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome bluetooth applet ->settings not finding bluetooth
Using the control-panel that comes with ubuntu 22.04, I'm unable to see my bluetooth adapter, except to turn it on and off. Settings displays no-bluetooth found.
The blueman-applet displays bluetooth fine.
When I start the gnome-control-center --verbose, I notice this
10:01:19.0736                 Bluetooth:    DEBUG: Default adapter changed to: (none)
10:01:19.0744         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill,org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill)
10:01:19.0748         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill,org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill) → 0x556799a1d870) to the storage
10:01:19.0748         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill,org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties)
10:01:19.0755         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill,org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties) → 0x5567999a5f80) to the storage
10:01:19.0755        bluetooth-cc-panel:    DEBUG: Updating airplane mode: BluetoothHasAirplaneMode 0, BluetoothHardwareAirplaneMode 0, BluetoothAirplaneMode 0, AirplaneMode 0
10:01:19.0755        bluetooth-cc-panel:    DEBUG: No Bluetooth available
10:01:19.0756                 cc-window:    DEBUG: Time to open panel 'Bluetooth': 0.035549s
10:01:19.0756                 cc-window:    DEBUG: Added 'power' to the previous panels
(gnome-control-center:383485): dconf-DEBUG: 10:01:19.757: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/session/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
(gnome-control-center:383485): dconf-DEBUG: 10:01:19.757: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/interface/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
(gnome-control-center:383485): dconf-DEBUG: 10:01:19.766: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
10:01:19.0776                 Bluetooth:    DEBUG: Not adding device 'vanaheim'
10:01:19.0776                 Bluetooth:    DEBUG: Not interested in device 'vanaheim'
10:01:19.0776                 Bluetooth:    DEBUG: Default adapter changed to: /org/bluez/hci0

Vanaheim is the "name" of adapter. Why would the bluetooth panel be ignoring it?
Updating with lsusb;sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    1.966550] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    5.729140] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.729163] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.729165] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.729169] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.729171] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.729174] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.801599] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.879098] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021
[   12.632216] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.632219] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.632222] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.208692] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.208701] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.208705] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[43267.998995] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000d532a1d1 failed to resubmit (2)
[43291.057320] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021
[44418.171080] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[128858.745663] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021


I have not heard of Vanaheim.  But, are you sure your devices are compatible with Linux?  I ask, because many BT devices are not.

Please edit the question to include results for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'

In terminal try bluetoothctl power on scan on exit
